# Redirect to location settings using cordova in android

Tags: android, cordova, gps, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Here is the requirements what i am trying to implement in my cordova android application

1. When user enters the home page check to see if  the gps is enabled or not.
2. If not enabled i want to point the  user to turn on the location settings.

first part is made easily with GPS detector plugin and second part is implemented using the web intent plugin.But its not working as i expected.

```
if(!gps){
     //gps is disabled try to show the location setting using webintent plugin
    window.plugins.webintent.startActivity(
        {
            action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS,
        },
        function() {},
        function() {
            alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent.');
            console.log("Failed to open URL via Android Intent. URL: " + theFile.fullPath)
        }
    );              
}
```

I am getting this  error `Failed to open URL via Android Intent`.

Comment: Help me guys  please

Comment: I had the same problem but didnt solve it

Comment: What Plugin did you use to check gps? Please?

Comment: I've created my own gps detector plugin will updated in my github

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin). Once installed, you call it via JS something like:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
```

**UPDATE**

You can use [cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy) to request high accuracy location mode (i.e. GPS) directly from within the app. This will show a native confirm dialog and if user agrees, GPS will be enabled automatically with requiring user to manually change settings:

```
function onRequestSuccess(success){
    console.log("Successfully requested accuracy: "+success.message);
}

function onRequestFailure(error){
    console.error("Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
    if(error.code !== cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED){
        if(window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")){
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
        }
    }
}

cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFailure, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

Comment: @Root, how did you achieve this?

Comment: Nevermind! Although it was a phonegap plugin with the last commit on Oct/13 it worked out of the box with Ionic 1.0.0

Comment: @FernandoFabreti FYI I recently forked that repo in order to add documentation and publish the plugin to npm and cordova registries - the forked repo is [here](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin)

Comment: Great! I have noticed that `Diagnostic.prototype.isGpsEnabled` always returns `true` on my Galaxy S4 Device. Your doc says your 'similar' version returns `true` only on high precision enabled, have you changed that? Will take a look at your code, thanks.

Comment: I haven't changed the code in my fork - just added documentation based on the code comments, so it may be my docs are wrong.

Comment: Thank you Very much helped me a lot