# How to know if camera is enabled on the device using ionic framework?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova, mobile-development

I'm developing an application with the superb ionic framework, and i'm stuck with my preferences page. I know how to load the camera plugin and everything needed to make the camera work. My problem is that I need to have a toggle button in my preferences page where user can activate or deactivate the camera usability setting for this app.

Anyone know where I can find info or documentatioon on how to acccess the actual app settings of the device.

Thanks !

[image: My Camera Settings]

*( Something like that )*

Comment: http://phandroid.com/2015/05/28/android-marshmallow-app-permissions/ until then, it looks like permissions are fixed configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application ask permission on installation based on phonegap configuration. I don't think you can disable permission at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can add posibility to change phone's settings, but you can redirect user to phone's settings and kindly ask to do what you want. Check out [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441993/redirect-to-location-settings-using-cordova-in-android) for idea, how to do it.